# Limit over a path

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I don't know how to compute a limit over a path when it is not a specific point I have to look for.

[image: Function p(x,y)]

What is the procedure in this case? Do I have to find a point in which the function is not continous, or do I have to parametrize the curve in some way. No idea. Anything will help.

Comment: what do you mean by "limit over a path" ?

Comment: This is, I think, usually called finding a limit "along a path." You seem to have presented a function $p(x,y)$, but now what path are you trying to find a limit along?

Comment: Which curve are you taking a limit over? It depends heavily.

Comment: I mean that if $x=-y^2$ then the limit of the function is not computable. Normally they would ask you to compute a limit on  single point, not a set of points such that $x\neq-y^2$. That's what i'm trying to say. @Surb

Comment: The limit where ?

Comment: The exercise justs asks me to study the continuity of this function.@jMdA @Doubt

Comment: @Surb That's the point, it doesn't tell me any point specifically, it just tells me to study the continuity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is continuous at $(x,y)$ if $x \neq -y^{2}$ and discontinuous $(x,y)$ if $x = -y^{2}$. For discontinuity at $(-y^{2},y)$ with $y \neq 0$ consider  limit of $f(\frac 1 n -y^{2}, y)=1-ny^{2}$ as $n \to \infty$ This limit is $-\infty$ so $f$ is not continuous at $(x,y)$. Now consider the case $y=0$ and $x=-y^{2}=0$. In this case the limit of $f(\frac 1 n -y^{2}, y)=1-ny^{2}$ is $1$ whereas the limit of $f(x,y)$ along $x=0$ is $0$. Hence, $s$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$ either.